# Using an Array of buttons in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button, jsx

In react I have a code like this:

```
 var myButtons=[];
 /*Products is an array of objects where each object identify a product*/
 for (var p of Products) {
     var button = <button 
                       style={someStyle}
                       onClick={onClickFunction}>
                       p.name
                  </button>
     myButtons.push(button)
 }
```

I will use this react array of buttons on a render command. The problem I have is that I do not know how to make one of these buttons to show its label p.name through the onClickFunction.

Comment: The function can accept parameters

Comment: so, should I use:  
    var button = <button 
                       style={someStyle}
                       onClick={p.name => onClickFunction(p.name)}>
                       p.name
                  </button>

Comment: You can definitely do it like that, however, I'd suggest reversing your logic. You're iterating the products, but call a function that returns a `<button>` so that you can do something like: `<div>{Products.map(makeButton, this)}</div>` which will pass the data variable along into the callback. Much cleaner

Answer (score 4):

A simpler more user friendly way is to iterate the data with a function. (note that this does not take into account scope, so `this` may be needed if it's inside a component)

```
function makeButton(data) {
    return (
        <button 
            style={someStyle}
            onClick={() => onClickFunction(data.label)}> //pass parameter for callback here if binding isn't used
            data.name
        </button>
    );
}
```

Now you can simply use a binding map inside your div!

```
<div>
    {Products.map(makeButton, this)}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add your label as paremeter :

```
<button style={someStyle} onClick={p.name => onClickFunction(p.name)}>
    p.name
</button>
```

And :

```
onClickFunction = (label) => () =>{
    console.log(label)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use ES6 syntax and array `map`.
The `name` property should be unique, and don't forget provide a key for each button:

```
const myButtons = Products.map(p => (
  <button style={someStyle} onClick={e=>{ this.onClickFunction(e, p.name); }} key={p.name}/>
    {p.name}
  </button>
));
```

Using an arrow function, so it doesn't require `.bind(this)`. Add `e.preventDefault()` to prevent default behavior, if the buttons are in a `form`.

```
onClickFunction = (e, name) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  // Your button behavior goes here.
}
```